what to do when we find an answer that is not helpful for anyone?
Sometimes I find answers that are not helpful to anyone, but they stay there, hanging around,
I would like to flag them for a moderator to delete them.
I wonder as we have voting for closing questions, why we don't have a voting for deleting answers too.
one of such answers is this one

For users without the trusted user privilege:

If the answer is Not an Answer (NAA), that is if it is no sort of answer at all—even a wrong one—you can flag as NAA.

If the answer is unsalvageable through edits and young enough to still be flaggable as Very Low Quality (VLQ), you should do that.


Either NAA or VLQ flags will start a review process where others can recommend deletion or directly vote to delete, depending on their site privileges.

If the answer is too old for VLQ and you're certain (not just strongly of the opinion) that a VLQ review would have succeeded in deleting the answer, you can raise a custom moderator flag and explain why you think deletion is needed. Moderators tend to be conservative when assessing this, so be careful.

If the answer is too old for VLQ and you want the community to review an egregious example, post it here on meta.


Otherwise, just downvote and move on until you have earned trusted user. Other users with that privilege may cast their delete votes when they see the post, just as you did.

General guidance: How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion? in the FAQ.


why we don't have a voting for deleting

Speak for yourself :)
These votes only come with 20k unicorn points.

